# How to initialize kotlin spring project using gradle with groovy

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I'm learning spring with `kotlin`, and have some projects with it, but, my gradle scripts are always generated using kotlin dsl, I want to use groovy for them. *(Find info for kotlin dsl is a bit hard for me.)*

Can someone help me? I already try to use `start.spring.io`, spring tool suite. Also I try to make it by hand using `gradle init`

Comment: What have you tried and how has it failed? Using `gradle init` with 6.8.1 will ask you if you want to use groovy or kotlin DSL with one of the steps (at least for `basic` and `application` project type)

Comment: I don't know how to configure it, Wich dependencies or plugins use

Comment: And we can not help you unless you tail us, what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: I try to use the spring initializer, but if you choose android it always use kotlin for gradle scripts, in the spring tool suite the samen, and when I try to do it manually I read for a while wich libraries and kotlin compiler configurations I need but I dont get it

Comment: I just want to initialize a kotlin spring project using gradle with groovy

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an automated approach.
A manual migration is possible.
You could do a reverse this table and do a step-by-step manual migration.
https://github.com/bernaferrari/GradleKotlinConverter#-things-it-can-do